# How two handle errors in async calls in swift combine?

Tags: swift, combine

I have two async calls to fetch data from the server, but I want them to handle them as a single response, also want to handle errors for each response.

for example, here I have two methods `m1()`, `m2()` each can throw the different types of errors.

**We should wait to get a response of both** and show an error message based on its error type. If there is no error, continue with the flow.
Which operator do we have to use? I tried with `Publishers.Zip` & `Publishers.Map` not able to handle errors.

```swift
enum Error1: Error {
    case e1
}

enum Error2: Error {
    case e2
}

func m1() -> Future<Bool, Error1> {
    return Future { promise in
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            promise(.failure(.e1))
        }
    }
}

func m2() -> Future<String, Error2> {
    return Future { promise in
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
            promise(.success("1"))
        }
    }
}
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.!! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the the problem you are running into is related to the fact that a `Publisher` can only emit one error type. So any time you try to combine `m1` and `m2`, each of which has a different error type, then you run into type conflict problems.

There are a couple of ways you might choose to solve this problem.  I'm going to suggest one.  In my solution, each of your requests (your Futures) will use an error type of `Never`, but the success or failure of an individual request will be carried in a `Result`.  Here is the code in a Playground:

```
import Foundation
import Combine


enum Error1: Error {
    case e1
}

enum Error2: Error {
    case e2
}

func m1(shouldFail: Bool) -> Future<Result<Bool, Error1>, Never> {
    return Future { promise in
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            if(shouldFail) {
                promise(.success(.failure(.e1)))
            } else {
                promise(.success(.success(true)))
            }
        }
    }
}

func m2(shouldFail: Bool) -> Future<Result<String, Error2>, Never> {
    return Future { promise in
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
            if(shouldFail) {
                promise(.success(.failure(.e2)))
            } else {
                promise(.success(.success("1")))
            }
        }
    }
}

let subscribe = m1(shouldFail: false)
    .zip(m2(shouldFail: true))
    .sink {
        (m1:Result<Bool, Error1>, m2:Result<String, Error2>) in

        switch m1 {
            case .success(let boolResult) :
                print("M1 succeeded with result \(boolResult)")
            case .failure(_) :
                print("M1 failed")
        }


        switch m2 {
            case .success(let stringResult) :
                print("M2 succeeded with result \(stringResult)")
            case .failure(_) :
                print("M2 failed")
        }
    }
```

(Note that I added a `shouldFail` parameter to your m1 and m2 requests so that you can play with the different cases when one or the other requests fail).

Note that each of the Futures return a type of `Future<SomeKindOfResult, Never>`.  That means that the futures entering the combine pipeline have the same Error type (it happens to be `Never`).  This leads to the very odd looking construct of:

`promise(.success(.failure(.e1)))`

Which is a bit bizarre, but it says that the Future agrees that the request completed, and the `Result` carries the success or failure of that request.

The pipeline uses `zip` to wait until both requests complete.  The value coming out of the `zip` is a tuple `(Result<Bool, Error1>, Result<String, Error2>`. This tuple accurately represents the success or failure of each request as well as carrying the appropriate value in each case.

Comment: Thank you @ScottThompson for your detailed info.