# Executing 2 parallel network requests using Swift Combine

Tags: swift, combine

I am trying to load data from two different endpoints using two different publishers which have different return types. I need to update the UI when both requests complete, but both requests can also fail so `Zip` doesn't do the trick. Usually I would use a `DispatchGroup` to accomplish this, but I have not figured out how to do that using Combine. Is there a way to use DispatchGroup with Combine?

```
let dispatchGroup: DispatchGroup = .init()
let networkQueue: DispatchQueue = .init(label: "network", cos: .userInitiated)

dispatchGroup.notify { print("work all done!" }

publisher
    .receive(on: networkQueue, options: .init(group: dispatchGroup)
    .sink { ... }
    .receiveValue { ... }
    .store(in: &cancellables)

publisher2
    .receive(on: networkQueue, options: .init(group: dispatchGroup)
    .sink { ... }
    .receiveValue { ... }
    .store(in: &cancellables)
```

The notify is immediately executed. Is this not the right way of doing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How two handle errors in async calls in swift combine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71425444/how-two-handle-errors-in-async-calls-in-swift-combine)

Comment: When you call `notify`, there's no work in the queue, so the block gets executed immediately. Try putting some work into the queue first and then call `notify`.

Comment: I think you need zip because this ensures all publishers have emitted each. yes it can fail, but why would you want to proceed if any of the services fail? you should retry the whole operation again.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use the `Publishers.CombineLatest` which will take the two publishers and create a new publisher, with the result of the *latest* value from both streams:

```
Publishers.CombineLatest(publisher, publisher2)
    // Receive values on the main queue (you decide whether you want to do this)
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
        // Handle error / completion
        // If either stream produces an error, the error will be forwarded in here
    }, receiveValue: { value1, value2 in
        // value1 will be the value of publisher's Output type
        // value2 will be the value of pubslier2's Output type
    })
    // You only need to store this subscription - not publisher and publisher2 individually
    .store(in: &cancellables)
```

The `Publishers.CombineLatest` publisher, is what can be seen as the equivalent of using a `DispatchGroup`, where you call `dispatchGroup.enter()` for each network operation you initiate. However, one key difference is that the `CombineLatest` publisher will produce more than one value, if any of the publishers produce more than one value. For normal network operations, you don't need to worry about this. But if you find yourself in a situation where you only need the first or the first N values produces by the combined publisher, you could use the `prefix(_:)` modifier, which will make sure that you will never receive more than N events.

**EDIT:** Updated to fix typo in code.

Comment: this doesn't compile. also, what I am using merge many publishers for value1, and another network publisher for value2. im trying to connect the http status, even though one emits many times and another emits 1 time

Comment: You're right, `Publisher.CombineLatest` should have been `Publishers.CombineLatest` - that was a typo  Could you elaborate more on what you actually need to achieve?